# Why does FirebaseListObservable list subscription get called multiple times during initialization?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

When I initialize a FirebaseListObservable list then subscribe to it, if I have 3 items in the list, the subscribe method will get called 0 items, then 1, then 2, then with all 3 items. So the code below:

```
let subscription = this.af.database.list('/items')
  .subscribe(x => console.log('x', x));
```

Will log to the console:

```
x []
x [ Object ]
x [ Object, Object ]
x [ Object, Object, Object ]
```

Is there a way to skip right to all 3 items rather than this progressive increment?

Comment: Which version of AngularFire2 are you using? This comment suggests it ought to be behaving the way you want it to: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.5/src/database/firebase_list_factory.ts#L107-L111

Comment: Perhaps a related issue: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/574

Comment: @cartant I'm currently using 2.0.0-beta.5. Great finds btw! Hmmm, looks like they are still looking into what the problem is specifically.

Comment: Same problem, just started occurring after upgrading to 2.0.0-beta.5. Guess I shouldn't have upgraded ;(

Comment: Late response but hopefully this helps `this.af.database.list('/items').$ref.on('child_added', (snapshot) => { ... }`